# What's the correct way to present form with multiple options on mobile?

Tags: usability, forms, mobile-application, responsive-design

I'm currently working on satisfaction survey which will be available also on mobile devices.

I have two variants of layout:

[image]

I prefer version A because is easier to read (one reading direction).
On the second hand, benefit of version B is availability of all options on screen without scrolling.

Do you have any idea which one is better in terms of usability ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're simply asking for responses on a scale of 0-10 (looks like it might be for NPS) then why not use a slider? That way you save a lot more screen real-estate than either of the two options presented here.

If you're thinking of other multiple choice scenarios then there are lots of different ways to present the choices based on the questions you're asking: some may require the user to be able to compare options (they all need to be visible) while other may be a definite answer to a specific question with limited possibilities (only a few answers need to be available).

Not all of them need to be presented as lists.

Answer (score 1):

Version A:

- Leaves out options. This makes extra "effort" to the user who will likely tap any of the ones he has on screen before scrolling.
- The positive ones are left in the bottom. I don't know if this is on purpose though.

Version B:

- All options are visible
- As buttons are in two rows and the space left between rows is the same as the one between columns it gives the impression that numbers are related in pairs (0&6, 1&7, 2&8, etc.). You could also try two columns one aligned to the left with the label "0 - Not likely" and the other the right aligned with the other label.

In more general terms I would try to reduce the options. Also, instead of assigning a number, assign an actual sentence which expresses the feeling (which you are asking for):

- I wouldn't recommend
- ...
- I might recommend
- I will definitely recommend